# Rows getting stretched by adjacent content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am maintaining a web page that uses bootstrap 2.3.2, and I have come across the following issue. The page is split into a sidebar and a main container, inside the main container there are fluid rows. These rows get shifted downwards by the content in the sidebar. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and/or propose a workaround? Some code is below, fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7137/).

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="left-div">
    <p>Some content here</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
        <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
<div class="right-div">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <h3>Stuff here</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            This row gets stretched vertically
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <p>This content gets pushed down</p>
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  float: left;
}

.right-div {
  margin-left: 220px;
  border-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: working fine in http://jsfiddle.net/epXrL/ ..please provide us a live example which demonstrates your problem???

Comment: You need the bootstrap css and js, they should be included in the fiddle link in the question

Comment: What Browser are you using? Have you tried different browsers? Do you have other css files overwriting bootstrap.css files? Are all DOM elements closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't mix pixels with % (fluid is %), and try to use the bootstrap grid, you will get less jumpy behavior!

```
.right-div {
  /* --> margin-left: 220px; <-- */
  border-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 25px;
}


.left-div {
  /* --> width: 200px; <-- */
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  /* --> float: left; <-- */
}
```

The float left is the issue! Don't use floats with fluid rows or use a clearfix afterwords, since fluid-rows uses floating heavily I assume ... Also the margin-left is the issue, right-div is somewhat floating but really isn't.

Comment: The float left was the issue, I changed to position: absolute instead

Answer (score 0):

When you are using container fluid,its better you give all the values in % rather pixels, try removing floats, border-left properties, instead place your divs properly inside your span elements.You dont require rightdiv leftdiv classes, just place your left contents inside (span3) and right contents inside (span9).Just an example..